# How to mount disks automatically without fstab?

Tags: disk-image

When I update my system, I always set up the disks to be mounted automatically. The standard behaviour of Ubuntu is unsuitable for my purposes since there are programs accessing disks before I have opened it.

I could edit /etc/fstab. As a matter of fact, everyone told me to follow this step. However, I would really like not to use fstab.

I'm blind, I use the computer by means of screen readers and I don't know if the problem is due to it, but the fact is that, having tried to edit fstab several times, I only got crashes in the system. For twice, I have had to reinstall the system becose of it. I wouldn't like to try it again.

I know: I could try again, again and, sometime, I would be successful. But how many reinstalations would be neded else? No, I prefer to invest in another way.

In previous versions of Ubuntu, I solved this question adding the following command to /etc/rc.local: "mount /dev/sda2 /home/luciano/disk1". It worked very well until rc.local is excluded in the new version of Ubuntu.

So, without rc.local, how can I set up this command to be run just after the initialization?
This is my first message. I’m happy to find a community so big, dynamic and interesting like that.
I thank you for any help!
Best regards,

Luciano

Comment: I apologize for not knowing this, but if you can use graphical applications, the "Disks" application has a checkbox "mount at startup" on each partition which effectively does the fstab edit for you.

Comment: Thank you for the help. By means of graphical interface, I got my disk  monted. Although simpler, in reality, I didn't know this feature. Thank you again and have a nice wekkend.

Best Regards, Luciano

Comment: Glad it worked out!